# How to add pagination in UICollectionView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a UICollection view which shows items. Now I want to add pagination on UICollectionView. I do not want to use any third party for this functionality. Please let me know how I can achieve this!

I have four one example http://slicode.com/bottom-refresh-control-uicollectionview/

But in this I have to drag scrollview upwards for few second to make it work.

Comment: Check for collectionView contentOffset and call the next page if the scroll reaches the bottom. You can programmatically start refreshing the refreshControl as well.

Comment: can you provide some code for that?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes I have accepted your answer.Doing with those classes is super easy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add bottom refresh control you have to use below helper class.

https://github.com/vlasov/CCBottomRefreshControl/tree/master/Classes

Download this 2 files which is in Objective-C. You have to import this file in Bridging header

```
#import "UIScrollView+BottomRefreshControl.h"
```

Add refresh control like this.

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
refreshControl.triggerVerticalOffset = 50.0 
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(paginateMore), for: .valueChanged) 
collectionView.bottomRefreshControl = refreshControl
```

This helper class provide you new `bottomRefreshControl` property, which helps you to add refresh control in bottom.

Comment: How  fetchNextData() relate with refresh here.Which method should be called

Comment: @Techiee replace `#selector(refresh)` with `#selector(fetchNextData)` might work for you.

Comment: I added refresh control as subview in collection view but It did not show in footer. It shows as collection view top as pull to refresh

Comment: @Techiee Is you scroll only vertical/ Horizontal direction or in both direction

Comment: vertical direction only

Comment: Ohk then it's too easy

Comment: You have to implement scroll delegate method

Comment: So can you post some working code because I am not able to understand how to show indicator bottom of collection until data is fetched by api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176211/discussion-between-jaydeep-and-techiee).

Answer (score 8):

Easy way to do that

```
 var page: Int = 0
 var isPageRefreshing:Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    YourApi(page1: 0)
}

 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if(self.mycollectionview.contentOffset.y >= (self.mycollectionview.contentSize.height - self.mycollectionview.bounds.size.height)) {
        if !isPageRefreshing {
            isPageRefreshing = true
            print(page)
            page = page + 1
            YourApi(page1: page)
        }
    }
}
```

In your api methods

```
func YourApi(page1: Int) {
    let mypage = String(page1)
    let request: String = String.init(format:"apiName/%@", mypage)
    print(request)
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 5):

I have added the functionality of load more in one of my application so let me give you the code

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        if arrData.count > 0 && isLastPageReached == false
        {
            return CGSize(width:(collectionView.frame.size.width), height: 100.0)
        }
        return CGSize.zero

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter {

            let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "footer", for: indexPath)


            let loading = UIActivityIndicatorView()
            loading.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
            loading.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            loading.tintColor = UIColor.gray
            loading.tag = -123456
            view.addSubview(loading)
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: loading, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            vew.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: loading, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))


            return view
        }
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if elementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter {

            if let loadingView = view.viewWithTag(-123456) as? UIActivityIndicatorView{
                if arrData.count > 0 && isLastPageReached == false 
                {
                    loadingView.startAnimating()
                    self.loadMore()
                }
                else
                {
                    self.isLoadMore = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementOfKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if elementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter{

            if let loadingView = view.viewWithTag(-123456) as? UIActivityIndicatorView{
                loadingView.stopAnimating()
                loadingView.removeFromSuperview()

                self.isLoadMore = false
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you maintain isLastPageReached ? Where this function is used self.removeLoadMoreView ?

Comment: @Techiee that bool you need to manage in api response. I got total number of page and current page if both are same then that bool is will become true otherwise false
Where this function is used self.removeLoadMoreView ? - Let me edit my answer

Comment: Please which constants did you define? eg `isLoadMore`

Answer (score 3):

Please try this it works for me.

Step 1:

Declare a global variable :

```
var totalCount : NSInteger?
var isGetResponse : Bool = true
var activityIndiator : UIActivityIndicatorView?
```

Set the viewDidLoad:

```
activityIndiator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.midX - 15, y: self.view.frame.height - 140, width: 30, height: 30))
    activityIndiator?.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .white
    activityIndiator?.color = UIColor.black
    activityIndiator?.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndiator?.backgroundColor = COLOR.COLOR_TABLEVIEW_BACKGROUND
    activityIndiator?.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    self.view.addSubview(activityIndiator!)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: activityIndiator!)
```

Step 2:
Set the value in the api call method:

```
self.totalCount = array.count
self.isGetResponse = true
```

Step 3: 
Write this code :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {


if isGetResponse {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        if totalArrayCount! > self.arrProductListing.count{

                isGetResponse = false
                activityIndiator?.startAnimating()
                self.view.bringSubview(toFront: activityIndiator!)
                pageIndex = pageIndex + 1
                print(pageIndex)
                self.getProductListing(withPageCount: pageIndex)
            }
        }

        //LOAD MORE
        // you can also add a isLoading bool value for better dealing :D
    }
}
```

In service call you can send the page index and from the server end they send back the response.

Thank you.

Comment: where did you define `totalArrayCount` and `pageIndex` this solution looks good but very confusing

Comment: Thanks, for me it's better to use `scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height`

Answer (score 3):

CollectionView Delegate method: Load More data on Scroll Demand on CollectionView.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == numberofitem.count - 1 {  //numberofitem count
            updateNextSet()  
        }
}

func updateNextSet(){
       print("On Completetion")
       //requests another set of data (20 more items) from the server.
}
```

Comment: I do not recommend this solution. There will be duplicated API request while count of cells are less or equal to visible cell count.

Comment: Hope you understand, This is the answer for the technical solution API you have to think about it logically and introduce page count and item count to get it to work properly. It depends mostly on server-side response page count rather than item count.

Answer (score 2):

The following two function are responsible for the pagination. As you can see below.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if current_page < total_page && indexPath.row == cars.count - 1 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "loading_cell", for: indexPath) as! PaginationCollectionViewCell
        cell.actIndicator.startAnimating()

        return cell
    }else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PaginationCollectionViewCell
        cell.lbTitle.text = cars[indexPath.row].company_name
        cell.lbDescription.text = cars[indexPath.row].engine_power
        return cell
    }
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if current_page < total_page && indexPath.row == cars.count - 1 {
        current_page = current_page + 1
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
            self.fetchData(page: self.current_page)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used that code while doing pagination. 
The point is; catching the loaded cell index while collection view is loading and control it's mod with a number and fetch datas seperately with page size field in the api (if there is). You can decide which number will be smaller than this calculation and you will control it.

For example you fetched 5 datas and loaded it and, if this state is ok, you will fetch the other 5. Here is the sample code for that.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = self.parentViewController as? SellController {
            if vc.dontFetch == false {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if self.salesData.count > 3 {
                        if indexPath.row != 1 {
                            if indexPath.row % 3 == 1 {
                                print("indexpath: \(indexPath.row)")
                                vc.pagination += 1
                                vc.reload()

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this code i am controlling indexpath.row % 3 == 1 or not. It can be little bit complex so i can share a code block if you want. Good luck:)

Answer (score 1):

-- **itemList** - your data array.

-- **pageCount** - variable used to keep track of the number of pages.

-- **totalCount** - total number of data

--- append data to **itemList** every time you call the API.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == itemList.count - 1 && itemList.count < totalCount{
        pageCount += 1
        // Call API here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in `willDisplay cell` method calls load more function while your scroll is 5 cells away from the end. While fetching data show loader in collection view footer. Hide footer when loading is completed.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
        let currentPage = collectionView.contentOffset.y / collectionView.frame.size.width;
        if (aryDataSource.count >= yourAPIResponsebatchCount && aryDataSource.count - indexPath.row == 5 && currentPage >= currentPage && isDataLoading) {
            currentPage++;
            self.fetchMoreData()
        }
        else { }
}
```