# How to correctly update CollectionView, when I swipe UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, reloaddata

I need to resolve problem: my Views into CollectionView not updating correctly when I swipe UIScrollView. I want to get update after scroll complete, but instead my View are updating every time when UIScrollView is moving.

**My code:**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offSet = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let width = scrollView.frame.width
        let horizontalCenter = width / 2
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(offSet + horizontalCenter) / Int(width)
        
        currentIndex += 1

        if currentIndex == viewModel.weather.count {
                currentIndex = 0
        }
        
        self.cityLabel.text = self.viewModel.weather[currentIndex].now.name 
        
        self.todayCollectionView.reloadData()
        
    }
```

Comment: Use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619379-scrollviewdidendscrollinganimati) instead

Comment: Unless by "complete" you mean you see the last item in the collection.

Comment: If you want to paginate based on the end, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282164/how-to-add-pagination-in-uicollectionview-in-swift/51511319)

Comment: @Jake thank you!!!